# Gulp emit task end after async call

Tags: gulp

I am using gulp `run-sequence` and one of my tasks includes a custom remote call to a webservice and I don't want gulp to move on until it's complete, however it immediately moves on because I don't have the proper return.

```
gulp.task('upload', function() {

    fs.readFile('./dist.zip', { encoding: 'base64' }, function(err, data) {
        params['ZipFile'] = data;

        lambda.updateFunctionCode(params, function(err, data) {
            return true;
        });
    });
});

// Our default task will build a production copy, then upload to Lambda
gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
    return runSequence(
        ['clean'], ['js', 'npm', 'env'], ['zip'], ['upload'],
        callback
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the callback in the 'upload' task so you can signal when that task is done. Like this:

```
gulp.task('upload', function(callback) {
    fs.readFile('./dist.zip', { encoding: 'base64' }, function(err, data) {
      params['ZipFile'] = data;
      lambda.updateFunctionCode(params, function(err, data) {
          callback();
      });
    });
});
```

Also do't forget to check for errors on the above fs.readFile and lambda.updateFunctionCode: if(err)...

Comment: ah thank you didn't realise I could pass a callback to that function. Re: error checking, I deleted a huge code block for readability :)